# RouterLink Angular 13

Tags: angular, router, angular13, routerlink

Hola comunidad quisiera saber como no realizar scroll al redireccionarme a otro componente desde el enlace que tengo en mi componente footer, al redireccionarme me toca realizar scroll para ver mi formulario.

```
<a routerLink="/form">Formulario<a>
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: a ver si entiendo queires redireccionar y al mismo tiempo que haga scroll a un punto de la pagina...

Comment: deberias agregar mas contexto (codigo a tu pregunta...)

Comment: cuando redirecciono desde el footer paso a otro componente pero ese tambien tiene un footer y al redireccionarme no me posiciona en mi formulario me toca hacer scroll para llegar a el porque tengo otros componentes debajo de el, entonces quiero es llgar directo al fomulario mas no tener que hacer scroll, me redirecciona bien pero desde el componente debajo del fomulario

Comment: mira mi respuesta y ponle algo que identifique al form.